# positioning eight divs onto the page

Tags: html, css, positioning

So I have this html and this css. I want the .big elements be displayed in the corners of my .About 
This is how it looks like so far using this code

[The output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKeSZ.png)

I would like the first .big .box from the .left-box .container to be displayed on the top of .left-box .container and the first .big .box from the .right-box .container to be displayed on the top of .right-box .container. Rest of the div's should stay the same as they are.

```css
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

.big {
  height: 400px;
}

.arrow {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.top {
  top:0
}

.middle {
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-10px;
}

.bottom {
  bottom:0
}

.left {
  left:0;
}

.center {
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-10px;
}

.right {
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="About">
        <div class="left-box container">
            <div class="big box">
                <div class="arrow bottom right"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="big box">
                <div class="arrow top right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-box container">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="arrow bottom center"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <img src="images/marks.jpg" alt="marks" />
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="arrow top center"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-box container">
            <div class="big box">
                <div class="arrow bottom left"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="big box">
                <div class="arrow top left"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: replace className with class

Comment: sorry about that...I am doing all of this on React app